# Why the radio button appears in different style in different file?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, radio-button, adobe, flash-cs6

I have a question about radio button. I try to add radio button into my works and the size is smaller than the usual size. So, I try to re-do in new file, and the radio button size is normal. including the font and everything. But when I try to add into my work, the size back to smaller size and the font too. I already delete the scene and re-create the scene. But it is still same. Anyone can tell me why it is happened? Here I attached my screenshot from 2 different files.

[Normal size of radio button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6MIK.jpg)

[Not normal size of radio button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vska.jpg)

Comment: Could you put some snapshots of the different cases ? ...

Comment: @akmozo https://www.dropbox.com/s/kmj287c73bdngq3/Screenshot_radiobutton.rar?dl=0 here is my screenshot between two different files